# Narrow type based on conditional type(Typescript)

Tags: typescript

I want to create function type where one of the optional parameters are required.

As far as I get is to make conditional type but the problem is that in the function typescript can not narrow type based on this condition

```
type a = { propA: number };
type b = { propB: string };

type OneOfIsRequired = <T extends a | undefined, S extends b | undefined>
  (parameterOne: S extends undefined ? a : T, parameterTwo?: T extends undefined ? b : S, x: number) => any;

const fn: OneOfIsRequired = (a, b) => {
  if (a) {
    const propA = a.propA;
  } else {
    const propB = b.propB; // Object is possibly 'undefined'.. typescript can not narrow type based on first if statement
  }
};


fn(undefined, undefined, 1); // Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'a' OK !, one of parameter is required
fn({ propA: 1 }, undefined, 1);
fn(undefined, { propB: '1' }, 1);
```

so i would expected that in lse condition in my function typescript can narrow correct type which is type "b" and not "b | undefined"

Any idea how i can achieve this behavior? I do not want to retype it by myself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think conditional types are helping you much.  I'd probably instead use a union of [rest tuples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) to describe the possible arguments:

```
type OneOfIsRequired = (...args: [a, b | undefined, number] | [undefined, b, number]) => any;
```

This should give you the same results when you call it:

```
fn(undefined, undefined, 1); // error
fn({ propA: 1 }, undefined, 1); // okay
fn(undefined, { propB: '1' }, 1); // okay
```

But it has the benefit that the compiler is much more likely to be able to narrow a union to one of its consitutents than it is to be able to narrow a generic conditional type to one of its concrete values.

---

The implementation will still complain though, because TypeScript type guards will only narrow the type of a *single* value.  That is, in `if (a) { } else { }`, it's possible that the type of `a` will be narrowed inside the then and else clauses, but the type of `b` will not be narrowed when you check `a`, even if there is some constraint between the types of `a` and `b`.

The only way to have a type guard happen automatically is to have `a` and `b` part of a single value and check that single value.  You could make your own object like

```
const fn: OneOfIsRequired = (a, b, x) => {
  const obj = { a: a, b: b } as { a: a, b: b | undefined } | { a: undefined, b: b };
  if (obj.a) {
    const propA = obj.a.propA;
  } else {
    const propB = obj.b.propB; 
  }
};
```

*but* you already have an object kind of like this if you use the rest tuple in your implementation:

```
// use the arguments as a tuple
const fn: OneOfIsRequired = (...ab) => {
  if (ab[0]) {
    const propA = ab[0].propA;
  } else {
    const propB = ab[1].propB; 
  }
};
```

So this works but might be more refactoring than you want to do.

---

If all of this is too much work for you, just admit that you are smarter than the compiler and use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell it so.  Specifically, you can use [a non-null assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator) using `!`:

```
const fn: OneOfIsRequired = (a, b) => {
  if (a) {
    const propA = a.propA;
  } else {
    const propB = b!.propB; // I am smarter than the compiler 
  }
};
```

That `b!` just means that you've told the compiler that `b` is not `undefined`, no matter what it thinks.  And the error goes away.  This is less type safe than the above solutions, but it is much simpler and doesn't change your emitted JavaScript.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: i appreciate your effort, for now i did this kind of stupid thing "I am smarter than the compiler" (i really dont like this kind of code). But i will use this union type. Easy smart solution. I always complicate things in typescript. thx a lot