# Type narrowing of event callback based on the event key

Tags: typescript

While searching for options on how to write a type safe event emitter, i stumbled on this pattern where you first define your event names and their values in an interface, e.g:

```
interface UserEvents {
    nameChanged: string;
    phoneChanged: number;
}
```

and the '***on***' method is defined to take a *keyof* UserEvents, and a callback whose parameter is of the type pointed by the key obtained using the feature known as lookup type - UserEvents[keyof T]:

```
function on<T extends keyof UserEvents>(e: T, cb: (val: UserEvents[T]) => void) {/**/}
```

giving type safe method calls:

```
on('nameChanged', (val) => {}); // callback parameter type inferred to be a string
on('phoneChanged', (val) => {}); // ... inferred as number
```

The issue i have is inside the body of the '***on***' method where i can't narrow the type of the passed callback based on the passed key value. Since the event names and their types are defined in the same interface, i expected the callback to be narrowed if i checked for the key type but that is not the case:

```
function on<T extends keyof UserEvents>(e: T, cb: (_: UserEvents[T]) => void) {
    if (e === 'nameChanged') {
        // expecting the cb type to be (string) => void
    } else {
        // and here to be (number) => void
    }

    // but regardless of the checks, the cb type
    // inside the method body is of type (string & number) => void
}
```

Is there any way to achieve automatic type inference of the callback based on the event key, using other TypeScript features like type guards, discriminated unions, etc., with this specific method call signature?

Comment: i had similar question... "The implementation will still complain though, because TypeScript type guards will only narrow the type of a single value. That is, in if (a) { } else { }, it's possible that the type of a will be narrowed inside the then and else clauses, but the type of b will not be narrowed when you check a, even if there is some constraint between the types of a and b.". check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264378/narrow-type-based-on-conditional-typetypescript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to achieve wanted behavior, we need to compose both things into one data structure, fortunately when choosing [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) for such structure and combining it with spreading function arguments the result will match the exact need.

Consider below code:

```
interface UserEvents {
    nameChanged: string;
    phoneChanged: number;
}

// generic type in order to use with different objects then UserEvents only
type KeyWithCallback<A extends object> = {
  [K in keyof A]: [K, (_: A[K]) => void]
}[keyof A];

function on(...args: KeyWithCallback<UserEvents>) {
  if (args[0] === 'nameChanged') {
    const [_, clb] = args; // destructuring inside condition
    clb('') // here clb allows on string only (string) => void
  } else {
    const [_, clb] = args; // destructuring inside condition
    clb(1); // here clb allows on number only (number) => void
  }
}
// using
on('nameChanged', (a:string) => {}) // ok
on('nameChanged', (a:number) => {}) // error as expected
```

I have used [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) `KeyWithCallback` to represent all possible arguments as `[key, callback]` pairs. The result is a union of pairs (2-nd tuple).

`KeyWithCallback<UserEvents>` evaluates into:

```
| ["nameChanged", (_: string) => void] 
| ["phoneChanged", (_: number) => void]
```

The second important thing is to annotate function arguments `...args: KeyWithCallback<UserEvents>`. From now on, function body will understand that function has two arguments, and one relates to another, and this relation is described in every pair from the union type.

Checking first element of the pair automatically inference the second element.

Comment: Ach we can do even better by KeysWithCallback<A>[keyof A]. Will update my answer later

Comment: Jackpot with the 3rd solution!  It never occurred to me to tie the event with its callback in a tuple and change the definition of the method to take a rest parameter with the type being the union of those tuples, and the VsCode offers the expected intellisense both when the method is called and for the _if_ checks

Comment: @Codeceps I cleaned the answer, also there is no need for using manual union. So we have the union out of box from KeyWithCallback<UserEvents>