# TypeScript - type assertion for union of tuples - how to assert only one member and make TS figure out type of other members?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make type assertion for "error-first" pattern.

My function returns tuples like `['error', null]` or `[null, 'non-error']`.

I want to check only for `error === null` and TS should assume that the second member is not-null.

Here is an example which clarifies my needs:

```typescript
type ErrorMessage = string;
type ResultError = [ErrorMessage, null];
type ResultOk<T> = [null, T];
type Result<T> = ResultError | ResultOk<T>;

interface I {
    x: number;
}
function f(): Result<I> {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        return [null, {x: 1}];
    } else {
        return ['my-error', null];
    }
}

const [error1, result1]: Result<I> = f();

// works, but i dont want to check result1...
if (result1 !== null) {
    console.log(result1.x);
}

// instead i want to check if error is null,
// and assume result1 is I
if (error1 === null) {
    console.log(result1.x); // TS2531: Object is possibly 'null' <<=====
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow TS to narrow the type we can use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types). Consider below code:

```
const isOk = <T>(r: Result<T>): r is ResultOk<T> => r[0] === null; // type guard

const result: Result<I> = f(); // here result is either Ok or Error still

if (isOk(result)) {
  const [error1, result1] = result; // inside the if result is ResultOk
}
```

**Additional info** - yes you can do that by standard if statement `r[0] !== null` also, but having named type guard for custom structure is preferred way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost perfectly shaped to behave as you want.

There is one tiny detail: You shouldn't use destructuring when declaring the results variable, refer to it as a single value instead:

```
const result: Result<I> = f();

if (result[0] === null) {
  const {x} = result[1]
  console.log(x); // ok
}
```

This works as expected and you don't need to create any additional function or type guard.

Credits should go to this answer which explains really well why typescript behaves like this: [Narrow type based on conditional type(Typescript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264378/narrow-type-based-on-conditional-typetypescript#answer-55265125)

Comment: This condition is a type guard, but anonymous one. Having custom structure with named type guards is a preferred pattern. Or you want to have this result[0] check in every place.